# Excel "Nested IF" of multiple columns and multiple conditions per row

Tags: excel

I have a problem that seems so simple, but I can't wrap my head around it. I have a large database, and i have two separate columns that unfortunately need to stay that way, which together are defining the time of an incident: Column A consists of an integer number "1" to "12", and Column B consists of cells with either "PM" or "AM". I need a separate column that gives me a "1" for anything that happened between 8 AM and 4 PM and a "0" for all else. Part of the problem obviously are the "12" "PM" rows. That's all I have so far:

```
=IF(AND(A1>=8, A1<=11),IF(B1="AM",1,0),0)
```

, which puts out correctly a "1", if anything happened between 8 AM and 11 AM, but not the rest. I need to combine it with:

```
=IF(AND(A1>=1, A1<=4),IF(B1="PM",1,0),0)
```

and:

```
=IF(AND(A1=12),IF(B1="PM",1,0),0)
```

but I have no idea how to combine all of these in one statement at the same time. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

This was a fun exercise - I'm sure there's a dozen ways to do it but here's what I found:

```
=IF(AND(TIME(IF(B1="PM",A1+12,A1),0,0)>=TIME(8,0,0),TIME(IF(B1="PM",A1+12,A1),0,0)<=TIME(11,0,0)),1,0)
```

Goes in C1

So my approach was --

If B1 is PM, then give me A1 + 12 (hours), otherwise just give me A1

```
IF(B1="PM",A1+12,A1)
```

Return a time value equal to that many hours

```
TIME(IF(B1="PM",A1+12,A1),0,0)
```

Check and see if it's greater than a value of exactly 8 hours...

```
TIME(IF(B1="PM",A1+12,A1),0,0)>=TIME(8,0,0)
```

Then wrap it in an And statement with an identical function asking if it's less than 11.

I don't like that it repeats itself, and that I have to use `TIME(8,0,0)` to return a value of 8 hours.. Maybe you or someone else can offer improvements or other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this:

```
=IF(AND(TIMEVALUE(A1&" "&B1)>=(8/24),TIMEVALUE(A1&" "&B1)<=(16/24)),1,0)
```

Simple and direct. You just need to convert what you have to its equivalent time value(between 0-1 in Excel).
And then just evaluate it using *AND* operand with 8/24(8AM) and 16/24(4PM). HTH.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: =IF(AND(A1>=8, A1<=11),IF(B1="AM",1,0),0) + IF(AND(A1>=1, A1<=4),IF(B1="PM",1,0),0) + IF(AND(A1=12),IF(B1="PM",1,0),0)

Comment: =--OR(AND(OR(A1={8,9,10,11}),B1="AM"), AND(OR(A1={1,2,3,4,12}), B1="PM"))

Comment: However, I wanted to include these formulas in some form in the 'add calculated field' option of my pivot table, and there these did not work, but only returned "0"s in the pivot table. Any idea what I need to change to make it work? Note that I did change "A1" to the column name 'Hour', and "B1" to the column name "AM/PM" for the calculated field option